# use same process more than once

Tags: java, batch-file

is there any possible way to use the same process to run different commands ? i.e instead of creating new process each time ?

```
public static void removeAlphaChars() {
    try {
    String[] values = { "a", "12", "gbdasg", "asfwqer", "3", "5", "6", "7",
            "8", "9", "0", "-", "123" };
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
    String[] start = { "cmd", "/C"};
    builder.command(start);
    Process p = builder.start();


    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        String[] arg = { "cmd", "/C", "echo.bat", values[i] };

            builder.command(arg);
            p=builder.start(); //<<<<<<< THIS STARTS NEW PROCESS
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            p.waitFor();

            // System.out.println(p2.exitValue());
        } 

    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

as builder.start, starts new process which is consuming memory , how can i save my resources ?

Comment: So, to save resources is to write to the same memory space. Any child process should do its task and rejoin the parent thread. Resources are wasted if you are copying new memory for each process. To solve a race condition, which may occur, you need to look into mutex locks and semaphores.

Comment: Have you considered writing the code in Java? Calling an external process is inherently profligate with your resources.

Comment: Are you experiencing an actual problem? Or are you trying to avoid a hypothetical memory issue?  Maybe if you explain the real problem you're trying to solve you might get a better response.

Comment: yes.. creating 3 different batch files , and processor is 90-100% used

Comment: Your `p.waitFor()` should wait until each process is terminated; and when it's terminated, it should release all the memory it's used (or am I missing something)?  So I have a suspicion that you've misidentified the problem--like one of the commands in your batch file is using up all the resources or forgetting to release them.  I'm not an expert in `ProcessBuilder`, though.

Comment: creating/killing processes is just overhead , if it's only one process starting some commands , it would be more effiecent

Comment: Again, what don't you use the same memory to write in the main process? You'd share the same memory. Again, this sounds like a shared memory problem. Also, any input tasks are going to be CPU heavy.